# For loops, lists-of-lists, and conditional analyses (in R)

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I'm trying to compute a reaction time score for every subject in an experiment, but only using a subset of trials, contingent on the subject's performance.

Each subject took a quiz on 16 items. They then took a test on the same 16 items. I'd like to get, for each subject, an average reaction time score *but only for those items they got both quiz and test questions correct*.

My data file looks something like this:

```
subject   quizitem1   quizitem2   testitem1   testitem2   RT1   RT2
1         1           0           1           1           5     10
2         0           1           0           1           3     7
```

Ideally I'd like another column that represents the average reaction time for each subject when considering only RTs for items `i` with 1s under both `quizitem[i]` and `testitem[i]`. To use the above example, the column would look like this:

```
newDV
5
7
```

...since subject 1 only got item 1 correct on both measures, and subject 2 only got item 2 correct on both measures.

I've started by making three vectors, to help keep data from relevant items in the correct order.

```
quizacclist = c(quizitem1, quizitem2)
testacclist = c(testitem1, testitem2)
RTlist = c(RT1, RT2)
```

Each of these new vectors is very long, appending the `RT1`s from all subjects to the `RT2`s for all subjects, and so forth.

I've tried computing this column using `for` loops, but can't quite figure out what conditions would be necessary to restrict the analysis to the items meeting the above criteria.

Here is my attempt:

```
attach(df)
i = 0
j = 0

for(i in subject) {
    for(j in 1:16) {
        denominator[i] = sum(quizacclist[i*j]==1 & testacclist[i*j]==1)
        qualifiedindex[i] = ??
        numerator[i] = sum(RTlist[qualifiedindex])
        meanqualifiedRT[i] = numerator[i]/denominator[i] 
        }
    }
```

The `denominator` variable should be counting the number of items for which a subject has gotten both the quiz and test questions correct.

The `numerator` variable should be adding up all the RTs for items that contributed to the `denominator` variable; that is, got quiz and test questions correct for that item.

My specific question at this point is: How do I specify this `qualifiedindex`? As I conceive of it, it should be a list of lists; each index within the macro list corresponds to a subject, and each subject has a list of their own that pinpoints which items have `1`s under both `quizacclist[i]` and `testacclist[i]`.

For instance:

```
Qualifiedindex = ([1,5,9],[2,6],[8,16],etc)
```

Ideally, this structure would allow the `numerator` variable to only add up RTs that meet the accuracy conditions.

How can this list-within-a-list be created? 
Alternatively, is there a better way of achieving my aim?
Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using base R `reshape` and then `dplyr`:

```
quiz_long <- reshape(quiz, direction = "long",
  varying = -1, sep = "", idvar = "subject",
  timevar = "question")
quiz_long %>%
  filter(quizitem == 1 & testitem == 1) %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  summarise(mean(RT))
```

Note this will only include subjects who got at least one usable question. An alternative which will have NA for those subjects:

```
quiz_long %>%
  mutate(RT = replace(RT, quizitem != 1 | testitem != 1, NA)) %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  summarise(mean_RT = mean(RT, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the promising suggestion Nick! I've tried that out but currently stuck dealing with an error prompted by the mutate feature, where the replacement has a different number of rows than the data. Is there a common reason for why that occurs?

Thanks again,
Adam